# Update one of the objects in array, in an immutable way with immer.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immer.js

Say I have some initial state like

```
      const initialState = {
        post: { comments: {
           {0: {id:'1',name:'myname',statusdata: false}},
           {1: {id:'2',name:'yourname',statusdata: true}}, 
      },
   };
```

And I want add to data as the result of an action but the data I want to add is going to be an array. How do I go about this?

```
     export default produce((draft, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_NAME:
          draft.posts.comments.name = action.payload;
          break;
        case CHANGE_STATUS:
          draft.posts.comments.statusdata = !action.payload;
          break;
        default:
      }
    }, initialState);
```

I have this error

```
Error: [Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property
```

Comment: Would you post a sample of `draft.posts.comments` to figure out the data structure? As it looks like you're attempting to set object property, whereas either `posts`, or `comments`, or both appear to be an array. Also, it would be helpful to see `action.payload` structure.

Comment: Here ``post`` is don't array but ``comments``

Comment: `comments` doesn't seem to be valid object notation (no key for value `{name: ..`). Are you sure about that? And what's the `action.payload` format?

Comment: i have update my question, thank !

Comment: `comments` notation is still invalid (no key names for nested objects-values) - it has to be either an object with keys, like `comments: {0: {id: '1'..,} 1: {id: '2'..}}` or it is actually an array, but then square brackets should be used: `comments: [{id: '1'..}, {id: '2'..}]`

Comment: thank! is good now

Answer (score 0):

I have made assumptions on the schema of `comments` and `action.payload`. Try the following solution.

```
Object.values(draft.post.comments).map((comment){   
   if(comment.id == action.payload.id){
       const updatedComment = Object.extend({}, comment, {"name": action.payload.name});
       return updatedComment;
   }
   return comment;
})
```

Comment: This is assuming that `comments` is an array with square brackets `[..]`. and action.payload is an updated object with `id`, `name` and `statusdata`.
Example:
`{'id': 1, 'name': 'updatedname', 'statusdata': true}`

Comment: Please add an example of `action.payload`. How does it look?

Answer (score -1):

I'm try

```
    export default produce((draft, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_STATUS:
          draft.posts.comments[
             draft.posts.comments.findIndex(i => i.id === action.payload)
                    ].statusdata = action.payload;
                return draft;
        default:
      }
    }, initialState);
```

Comment: But before you try, learn english first.